# How do Interfaces in Solidity know which contract they are interfacing?

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, addresses, interfaces

To my understanding, an address at some point needs to be provided so that the name of the interface that you write in your code is linked to the existing external contract you want to interface with. **However,** I don't see an address being provided in the code of a lot of popular ERC20 tokens interfacing the ERC20 contract, for instance with Axie Infinity:

**INTERFACE DELCARATION:**

```
// File: token/erc20/ERC20.sol

pragma solidity 0.5.17;

contract ERC20 is IERC20 {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  uint256 public totalSupply;
  mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal _allowance;

  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    _approve(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

...
```

Source Code:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xbb0e17ef65f82ab018d8edd776e8dd940327b28b#code

I did a `Control + F` for `0x` in the source code, and apparently no addresses are written inside, which leads me to believe there is a step I'm missing where the addresses are written inside.

I noticed that the URL to the ERC20 token file is commented out, so does that mean an address wasn't needed in this case but rather the complier knew somehow that the file was located in:

```
token/erc20/ERC20.sol
```

However all the references to that address were commented out and not used as parameters in any function call.

The only other thing I was able to find was in the solidity documents referencing needing to reference libraries using the Commandline Complier for linking, and in this case it was talking about libraries and not interfaces (so not even sure if this is relevant):

> As the compiler cannot know where the library will be deployed at,
> these addresses have to be filled into the final bytecode by a linker
> (see Using the Commandline Compiler for how to use the commandline
> compiler for linking). If the addresses are not given as arguments to
> the compiler, the compiled hex code will contain placeholders of the
> form **Set**____ (where Set is the name of the library). The address
> can be filled manually by replacing all those 40 symbols by the hex
> encoding of the address of the library contract.

source: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html?highlight=library#libraries

**MY QUESTION:**

How then do contracts then link the interface objects they are making in their contracts with the external contract they are interfacing? I'm sure there might be a few ways to do it, feel free to walk through whichever ways you know and explain it to me like I was a newbie, which I admittedly am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two different concepts: implementing an interface and casting an address to an interface.

The ERC20 snippet you provided is a contract that implements an interface, i.e. inherits from it and defines functions that satisfy the requirements of that interface. This contract must be compiled and deployed to give it an actual address on the blockchain. You then publish/share the address and the interface definition in some way.

With that information anyone can import the interface definition and cast the address to it.:

```solidity
import "IERC20.sol";

...

function bar() {
    IERC20 token = IERC20(address(0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890));
    token.foo(x, y, z);
}
```

> I noticed that the URL to the ERC20 token file is commented out, so does that mean an address wasn't needed in this case but rather the complier knew somehow that the file was located in:

I think this comment was inserted by a tool that flattened the contract for verification (i.e. combined multiple files belonging to the project into a single, equivalent one). It just tells you in which file this piece of code originally resided. The compiler does not modify your source.

> The only other thing I was able to find was in the solidity documents referencing needing to reference libraries using the Commandline Complier for linking, and in this case it was talking about libraries and not interfaces (so not even sure if this is relevant):

This is related but, as you noticed, it's only for libraries not interfaces. There can be multiple contracts that satisfy a given interface and you can choose one at runtime by specifying the address. With libraries there's only one implementation and you provide its address on the command line as an argument for the compiler so that it can be hard-coded in the compiled bytecode. This is why, when you define a library called, say, `L`, you can refer to it as just `L` and not `L(address(0x...))`.

Comment: Oh I see, and that code for casting the address for the interface definition given would be placed where? Would it be in the same `.sol` contract , or are there other ways people generally cast it

Comment: It would be in a function in a completely different contract.

Comment: So there's a separate contract to the main contract and the interface code that has a function that tells the main contract which contract the interface is referencing? My brain just got more confused hahah. would you happen to have a reference to this? This is the part that's causing my confusion, I haven't seen where and when the casting of the address the interface is linking to happens.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "main" contract. In the situation where you would use an interface there are basically two parties: a contract that is being called and a contract that calls it. The former defines some functions and inheriting from an interface is just a way to formally declare what those functions are. The contract that calls it can cast an address to that interface as a way to tell the compiler what functions are available and what input they take. Knowing this the compiler can tell if your call is correct or not and encode it.

Comment: Unfortunately the official docs do not expand on it too much. It's more of a reference and the assumption is that you're familiar with basic concepts from other languages. There's a bit on how to define an [Interface](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#interfaces) and a bit about casting under [Contract types](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#contract-types) (casting to an interface is really no different than casting to an ordinary contract type).

Comment: Surprisingly, I also can't find good articles on the topic of interfaces specifically in Solidity. Maybe this SO answer will be helpful though: [I am having a difficulty of understanding interfaces in Solidity. What am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64733976/i-am-having-a-difficulty-of-understanding-interfaces-in-solidity-what-am-i-miss).